# ERROR AL COMPILAR APLICACION

Tags: android-studio, stax

espero que puedan ayudarme por favor, estoy intentando compilar mi aplicaciòn y me presenta estos 2 errores, la verdad no sé como solucionarlo, agradezco de antemano la ayuda que puedan brindarme. Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ERROR DEL CERTIFICADO

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:v1.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:v1.0.0.
> > Could not parse POM http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/github/ybq/AndroidSpinKit/v1.0.0/AndroidSpinKit-v1.0.0.pom
> > El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
> > Could not resolve com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:v1.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/com/github/ybq/AndroidSpinKit/v1.0.0/AndroidSpinKit-v1.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/com/github/ybq/AndroidSpinKit/v1.0.0/AndroidSpinKit-v1.0.0.pom'.
> > Certificate for <cardinalcommerce.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]
> Could not resolve lk.payhere.sdk:android-payment-sdk:1.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve lk.payhere.sdk:android-payment-sdk:1.0.0.
> > Could not parse POM http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/lk/payhere/sdk/android-payment-sdk/1.0.0/android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom
> > El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
> > Could not resolve lk.payhere.sdk:android-payment-sdk:1.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/lk/payhere/sdk/android-payment-sdk/1.0.0/android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/lk/payhere/sdk/android-payment-sdk/1.0.0/android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom'.
> > Certificate for <cardinalcommerce.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io, *.pe.jfrog.io]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

ERROR DE CODIGO;

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project E:\APLICACIONES\AdForest

[Fatal Error] library-2.1.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] onboarder-1.0.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] pix-1.4.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] libary-2.4.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] picasso-2.5.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] google-signin-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] richeditor-android-1.2.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] circleimageview-2.2.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] html-textview-3.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] android-async-http-1.4.9.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bannerslider-1.8.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] stripe-android-6.1.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] simpleratingbar-0.1.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] retrofit-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] okhttp-3.10.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] fresco-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] pageindicatorview-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] accept-sdk-android-1.0.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] gson-2.8.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] converter-gson-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] crystalrangeseekbar-1.1.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bubbleseekbar-3.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] countdownview-2.1.6.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] ratingdialog-1.0.8.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] paypal-android-sdk-2.13.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] library-1.0.44.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] expandablelayout-2.9.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] dexter-5.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] filepicker-2.1.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] dragrecyclerview-1.0.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] AndroidSpinKit-v1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] glide-4.6.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-plugin-places-v8-0.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-sdk-8.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] braintree-java-2.105.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] drop-in-3.7.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] anet-java-sdk-1.8.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] android-gif-drawable-1.2.19.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] jaxb-core-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] jaxb-api-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] stax-api-1.0-2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] jaxb-impl-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-android-sdk-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] glide-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.21.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] volley-1.1.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] auto-value-annotations-1.6.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-common-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-core-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-share-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-login-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-marketing-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-messenger-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-applinks-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] facebook-places-5.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] httpclient-4.3.6.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] androidannotations-api-3.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] okio-1.14.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] fbcore-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] soloader-0.5.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] nativeimagefilters-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] drawee-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] imagepipeline-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] material-calendarview-1.4.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] okhttp-3.12.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] soloader-0.6.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-sdk-geojson-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-accounts-0.2.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-telemetry-4.5.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-gestures-0.5.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-sdk-turf-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] timber-4.7.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-sdk-services-4.6.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] braintree-2.18.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] card-form-3.5.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] jackson-jr-objects-2.9.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] commons-csv-1.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] org.osgi.core-4.2.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] relinker-1.3.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] commons-logging-1.1.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] log4j-1.2.16.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] httpcore-4.0.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] httpclient-4.0.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] disklrucache-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] gifdecoder-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] annotations-4.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bolts-android-1.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] core-3.3.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] auto-value-annotations-1.6.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bolts-tasks-1.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] imagepipeline-base-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] okio-1.15.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-core-1.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] annotations-16.0.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-sdk-core-4.6.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] visa-checkout-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] core-2.18.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] paypal-one-touch-2.18.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] jackson-core-2.9.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] commons-codec-1.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.10.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bolts-applinks-1.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] retrofit-2.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] converter-gson-2.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] logging-interceptor-3.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] browser-switch-0.1.7.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] data-collector-2.18.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] kotlinx-coroutines-core-common-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] listenablefuture-1.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] pix-1.4.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] onboarder-1.0.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] libary-2.4.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] library-2.1.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] picasso-2.5.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] circleimageview-2.2.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] google-signin-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] richeditor-android-1.2.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] html-textview-3.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bannerslider-1.8.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] simpleratingbar-0.1.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] android-async-http-1.4.9.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] retrofit-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] okhttp-3.10.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] stripe-android-6.1.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] fresco-1.11.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] accept-sdk-android-1.0.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] pageindicatorview-1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] converter-gson-2.3.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] bubbleseekbar-3.4.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] gson-2.8.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] crystalrangeseekbar-1.1.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] countdownview-2.1.6.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] ratingdialog-1.0.8.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] expandablelayout-2.9.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] library-1.0.44.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] dexter-5.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] paypal-android-sdk-2.13.3.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] filepicker-2.1.2.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] glide-4.6.1.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] AndroidSpinKit-v1.0.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-sdk-8.4.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] dragrecyclerview-1.0.5.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".
[Fatal Error] mapbox-android-plugin-places-v8-0.9.0.pom:7:3: El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final coincidente "".

```
BUILD.GRADLE (:APP)
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.grabbit.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 45
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "2.3.7"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        resValue "string", "places_api_key", (project.findProperty("AIzaSyABpJKX8xdmJhLKqkpGYS8hjvjtvtCSJ7g") ?: "AIzaSyABpJKX8xdmJhLKqkpGYS8hjvjtvtCSJ7g")
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //loaderLIbs
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'


//whatsapp img
    implementation  'com.fxn769:pix:1.4.4'
//img Picker
    implementation 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.4.4'
//necesary libs
    implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.onboarding:onboarder:1.0.4'

    implementation 'com.github.MasayukiSuda:BubbleLayout:v1.2.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.9.0'
    implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
    implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.5'
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9'
    implementation 'com.github.victorminerva:AutoResizeEditText:0.1.0'
    implementation 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'

// JSON Parsing
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.4'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'
    implementation 'com.codemybrainsout.rating:ratingdialog:1.0.8'
//PaypPal
    implementation('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.droidninja:filepicker:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.wonshinhyo:dragrecyclerview:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:v1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v8:0.9.0'`


//Payment Dependencies
    implementation 'lk.payhere.sdk:android-payment-sdk:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.7.1'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.gateway:braintree-java:2.105.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
    implementation 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.8.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0'
    implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Mejor si pones los errores como texto. Uno lo tienes en el código y el otro con el certificado.

Comment: Claro, mira es lo siguiente, Ya lo he agregado

Comment: @ZetaelePa es la biblioteca  "BrainTree"?

Comment: @Jorgesys Como puedo revisarla?

Comment: @ZetaelePa agrega tu app/Build.gradle para revisar la dependencia

Comment: @Jorgesys Listo lo he agregado al final

Answer (score 0):

El problema se define aquí:

> El tipo de elemento "hr" debe finalizar por la etiqueta final
> coincidente "". > Could not resolve
> lk.payhere.sdk:android-payment-sdk:1.0.0. > Could not get resource
> 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/lk/payhere/sdk/android-payment-sdk/1.0.0/android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom'.
>
> > Could not HEAD 'https://cardinalcommerce.bintray.com/android/lk/payhere/sdk/android-payment-sdk/1.0.0/android-payment-sdk-1.0.0.pom'.
> > Certificate for <cardinalcommerce.bintray.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [.jfrog.io, *.int.jfrog.io, jfrog.io,
> > *.pe.jfrog.io]

En la parte derecha, busca la configuración de Gradle (elefantito) y **asegura tengas el "modo offline" de Android Studio desactivado**, vuelve a construir tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Siii, esta desmarcado

Comment: Exactamente me pudes decir que debo hacer, la verdad es que no sé como, agradezco muchisimo la ayuda que puedas brindarme

Comment: ve a Build > Clean Proyect y luego Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: Antes de hacer esto "clean project" debo primero corregir lo que me mencionaste anteriormente verdad? y si es así, como puedo corregirlo

Comment: Asegura que no este marcado el "modo offline".

Comment: Hola, no esta marcado, hice lo que me indicaste pero sigue mostrando estos 2 errores